# Nest Device Room(id or displayName) does not get updated in SDM api

Tags: nest-device-access

I add a device for the first time in Nest app, and I set the 'where' parameter e.g. Backyard, and complete the device add flow.

Now, in my own app, when I hit SDM api to get list of devices, it gives me a parentRelation object in there which tells where my device is assigned.

```
parentRelation: { parent: 'enterprises/eid/structures/sid/rooms/rid, displayName: Backyard}
```

But when I update the 'where' parameter inside the Nest app, under device settings to 'Family Room' for example.

This change would not appear in the SDM api. It would still give me the first configuration data when I added the device.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What room is the device located inside the Google Home App?

Comment: Are you still having this issue?

Comment: As per the design SDM does not respect Nest App. It follows GHA .